# Can I install Windows 10 Media Creation Tool through Rufus on Hiren's?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hiren

While booted into Hirens I downloaded Windows 10 Media Creation Tool and tried to extract it through Rufus to create a USB boot drive.

When in Rufus and I go to find the file it doesn't show up.

When I try to start the media creation tool I get a error code stating

```
The code execution cannot proceed because ×:\windows\system32\mfc42u.dll was not found. 
Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it just not possible to do this? Does hirens have another program I could use to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Rufus replaces the Media Creation Tool. If you are using Rufus then there is no reason to use the MCT. You should be downloading the ISO on a standard Windows installation. I seriously doubt Rufus nor MCT were designed to run on WinPE. MCT clearly wasn’t.

Comment: If you do not have access to a proper version of Windows then you should be able to directly download a Windows 10 ISO (CD/DVD) image from any other machine. Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO from a Linux of Android device and you will be able to download an image that Rufus can use without having to run the Media Creation Tool